# Is it possible to provide a constuctor with copy elision for member initialization?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I'm testing different modes for initializing class members with following small code:

```
struct S {
    S() { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
    S(const S&) { std::cout << "cc\n"; }
    S(S&&) noexcept{ std::cout << "mc\n"; }
    S& operator=(const S&) { std::cout << "ca\n"; return *this; }
    S& operator=(S&&) noexcept{ std::cout << "ma\n"; return *this; }
    ~S() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
};

struct P1 {
    S s_;
};

struct P2 {
    P2(const S& s) : s_(s) {}
    S s_;
};

struct P3 {
    P3(const S& s) : s_(s) {}
    P3(S&& s) : s_(std::move(s)) {}
    S s_;
};


int main() {
    S s;
    std::cout << "------\n";
    {
        P1 p{s}; // cc
    }
    std::cout << "---\n";
    {
        P1 p{S{}}; // ctor = copy elision
    }
    std::cout << "------\n";
    {
        P2 p{s}; // cc
    }
    std::cout << "---\n";
    {
        P2 p{S{}}; // ctor + cc
    }
    std::cout << "------\n";
    {
        P3 p{s}; // cc
    }
    std::cout << "---\n";
    {
        P3 p{S{}}; // ctor + mc
    }
    std::cout << "------\n";
}
```

As you see in comments, only in case of aggregate-initialization of `P1{S{}}` copy elision happens and our class is initialized without any copy/move constructor calls. I wonder if it is possible to provide a constructor which initialize members directly like aggregate initializer. Any idea?

**Update:**
I wonder if I have understood standard incorrectly, but from my understanding, something strange happens here:

1. For initializer list we have:

> *class-or-identifier ( expression-list(optional) )*:
> Initializes the base or member named by class-or-identifier using **direct initialization** or, if expression-list is empty, value-initialization

2. For direct initialization we have:

> If T is a class type, if the initializer is a prvalue expression whose type is the same class as T (ignoring cv-qualification), the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object. (copy elision)

So from this, I thought that for a initializer list like `s_(std::move(s))` copy elision should happen, isn't it?

Comment: You are copying the value into your class so I don't see how you'd avoid the copy?

Comment: @AlanBirtles but in case of aggregate initialization we practically copy value into class too, but copy elision happens. I wonder if I can provide similar behavior when providing a constructor.

Comment: By the way, do you compile with optimizations?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov how I can have such default constructor? it is not special constructor like copy constructor or move constructor. You get compile error with that line.

Comment: @Afshin you're right

Comment: @AlanBirtles in all 3 cases of `P1{S{}}`, `P2{S{}}`, and `P3{S{}}` I'm moving a temporary. But only in first case, copy elision happens (that does not have any constructor and aggregate initialization happens). I want to know if it is possible to provide a constructor that initialize class member directly or not.

Comment: Ah, sorry there is no elison going on here, `P1{S{}}` directly initialises the member as `P1` has no constructor, the others always have to go via the constructors and perform the relevant moves and copies

Comment: @AlanBirtles That is exactly my question. I wondered if I can create a constructor that directly initialize member using passed argument or not. I guess answer is no, although I added a small update to post from standard.

Comment: @Afshin `std::move(s)` is not a prvalue expression, it is a xvalue expression. Therefore the elision rule doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible to provide a constructor which initialize members directly like aggregate initializer.

Certainly. Write a constructor that doesn't accept an argument of the member type, but rather accepts arguments that are forwarded to the constructor of the member. In your case, the member type is default constructible, so you don't need to forward any arguments:

```
struct P4 {
    P4(): s() {}
    S s;
};
```

Comment: But in this mode, you practically don't pass `S` via an argument. it may not be default constructable. I want to know if in any case a passed argument can directly initialize member or not. In addition, I added a small update based on standard to my question.

Comment: @Afshin `it may not be default constructable` It must be somehow constructible, or else you cannot construct any instances. Whatever are the arguments needed to construct it, pass those to the constructor of `P4` and use those arguments to initialise the member.

Comment: Oh, sorry my mistake. yea it needs to be default constructible. I got what you mean.

Comment: I thought of an idea with template like this: `struct P4 { template<typename... Args> P4(Args&& ... args) : s_(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {} S s_; };`. it provides what you meant. Though it works with only 1 class member.

Comment: `P4(Args&& ... args)` might introduce issues with copy/move constructor of `P4`. :-(

Comment: @Afshin: As for `std::pair`,  `std::piecewise_construct` with `std::tuple` for multiple members.

Comment: @Afshin Using such template constructor doesn't make much sense unless the `P4` itself is templated, or `S` has a template constructor.